# Java JNA writing memory boolean

Tags: java, jna

I'm hacking a game and I'm using Java `JNA` to write memory to the game, I can only write byte arrays but I need to write `booleans` as well (if that makes sense). So this is my write methods

VKernel32.java

```
public abstract boolean WriteProcessMemory(Pointer paramPointer1, long paramLong, Pointer paramPointer2, int paramInt, IntByReference paramIntByReference);
```

Actual Memory Writing:

```
public void writeMemory(int address, byte[] data) {
    int size = data.length;

    Memory toWrite = new Memory(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        toWrite.setByte(i, data[i]);
    }    
    kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(process, address, toWrite, size, null);
}
```

In C++ I can use a template for-say to do something like this

```
template <class T>
void Write(DWORD addr, T val) {
    WriteProcessMemory(_process, (LPVOID)addr, &val, sizeof(T), NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Memory consists of bytes. If you want to write something more "high-level" (such as a boolean) you need to think about how you want to represent that as bytes and encode it that way. If you are hacking a game, your design choices here are limited to what the game thinks a boolean should look like in memory.

Comment: Ya, in C++ I can use a template for-say to do something like this

 template <class T>
 void Write(DWORD addr, T val) {
  WriteProcessMemory(_process, (LPVOID)addr, &val, sizeof(T), NULL);
 }

Comment: In Java, you can write a method that does the same for a boolean.

Comment: that's what I'm trying to figure out haha, any clue?

Comment: well, figure out what you want to to write for `true` and `false` (maybe 0x01 and 0x00 or 0xFFFFFFFF and 0x00000000) and then write that into your byte-array function.

Comment: that's the thing, I don't know how to write true or false in my byte-array function, can you explain a little more?

Comment: If you decide you want to write `false` as `0x00000000`, you would call `writeMemory(address, new byte[]{0,0,0,0})` But the real problem is finding out what your game expects there. For example, how many bytes that boolean should have. A whole 32bit word? Just one byte? Just one bit as part of a packed array?

Comment: Right now I'm writing 4 bytes, so is that how I would do it?